# What is the difference between non-static method and static method of an abstract class?

Tags: c#, access-modifiers

I know it is not a best practice to use Static method in Abstract class, but what is the difference If I use both Static and non static method in abstract class.

I am assuming there is no difference in calling these methods, because we can't create instance for Abstract Class so we can call both Static and Non-static method using class name only.

Is there any other difference between them apart from the keyword 'Static'?

Ex:
Abstract Class:

```
abstract public class AbstractClass
{
    #region Constructor
    protected AbstractClass(Args args): this(args)
    {
    }
    #endregion

    #region public static methods

    public static object FormLoad(Args args)
    {
        //Logic 
    }

    public static object Sample(Args args)
    {
        //Logic
    }

    #endregion


    #region Public non-static methods

    public AbstractClass CreateResponse(Args args)
    {
        //Logic
    }

    public void ClearDialog()
    {
        //Logic
    }

    #endregion

    #region Abstract Method
    abstract protected void Responses();
    #endregion

}
```

Derived Class:

```
   public class DerivedClass : AbstractClass
   {
    #region Public Constructors

    public DerivedClass(Args args)
        : base(args)
    {
    }

    #endregion

    #region Protected Methods

    protected override void Responses()
    {
        //logic
    }

    #endregion
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use public static method of an abstract class as any other public static method. For example:

```
Logger.Configure();
```

You don't need instance of `Logger` to call `Configure` that way. And you **can't** call non-static methods of type without creating instance of that type. So, `Logger.NonStaticMethod()` won't work.

public or protected static methods can be called within class overload. You **can't** override them so they usually used as some kind of utility methods or as a non-overridable part of *template* method:

```
public class DerivedClass: AbstractClass
{
    public DerivedClass(Args args)
        : base(args)
    {
    }

    protected override void BuildResponses()
    {
        FormLoad(args);
    }
}
```

Also, public static methods sometimes used as factory methods:

```
public abstract class Logger
{
    public static Logger NLog()
    {
        return new NLogLogger();
    }
}

...

var logger = Logger.NLog();
logger.Log("Message");
```

You can see example of such usage in many places inside BCL: `WebRequest.Create(...)`, for example, creates `HttpWebRequest`, `FtpWebRequest` and others which are derived from `WebRequest`.

Answer (score 1):

Let me try to answer both of your questions -

> I know it is not a best practice to use Static method in Abstract
>   class, but what is the difference If I use both Static and non static
>   method in abstract class

It is legitimate to have both static and non-static methods in your abstract class and yes, you are right in your beliefs that it is not a best practice to use Static method in Abstract class. When I conceptualize an `abstract` class, it should be intangible, simply abstract, like Shape. It is only when some class inherits an abstract class it gets life and make sense in real world like Circle or square. So yes you can use static and non-static methods just like with any other class, it would make little sense with abstract classes.

> Is there any difference in calling these methods? When static method
>   of an abstract will be invoked since we can't create object for an
>   Abstract class.

You can call a non-static method on the instance of the class as usual, and yes you are right that 
we can't create object for an abstract class, static method will be called directly with class name like this, and it called as soon at compiler is executing the statement.

```
MyAbstractClass.StaticMethod();
```