# What is difference between abstract class static method and normal class static method?

Tags: c#, .net

I have two classes one abstract and another is normal class. and both are having static methods and calling same way and producing result successfully.

Abstract class static method:

```
public abstract class AbstA
{
    public static void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Abstract Class static method");
    }
}
```

Normal class static method:

```
public class NormalA
{
    public static void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Normal Class static method");
    }
}
```

Both are successfully running.

```
AbstA.Print();
NormalA.Print();
```

So what is difference between both classes?

Comment: Why you think that `abstract` is related to `static`?  The former is an OOP term, it means it's a class that is not fully implemented, the child classes must provide this functionality. But static is not related to OOP at all. You can call static methods even without an instance, it's kind of helper method, you don't have access to an instance of the surrounding class.

Comment: `So what is difference between abstract class static method and normal class static method?` Nothing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between non-static method and static method of an abstract class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36742276/what-is-the-difference-between-non-static-method-and-static-method-of-an-abstrac)

Comment: @TimSchmelter If we can call same method directly from the class name, so which one is best to implement this type scenario?

Comment: @sanjay: both aren't related. If you need an abstract class, create an abstract class, otherwise (default) use a normal/concrete class. If a method is static or not is not related to it at all. So if you need a static method that doesn't need an instance of that class, create a static method, otherwise create a non-static method. It's like asking if an automatic gear fits better to a red or blue car.

Answer (score 2):

There is no diff in the static methods in abstract and regular classes, since the static methods are called without instantiating the class.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference between **abstract classes**, **normal classes** and even **static classes** when you want use static members of them.
**Difference is when you want instantiate each of them.**

### When a class is **Normal**:

**You can instantiate it.** Like any normal class that you may have.

### When a class is **Abstract**:

**You cannot instantiate it.** When you have an abstract class, you can have class members(methods, properties) that are not implemented. Because of that you can not instantiate it.
[If you want to know more about abstract classes visit this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/abstract-and-sealed-classes-and-class-members)

### When a class is **Static**:

**You cannot instantiate it.** When a class is static it can just contain members that are static. so you cannot instantiate it.
[If you want to know more about static classes visit this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members)

Answer (score -1):

In awnser to your question: there is no difference for the static methods. What they are housed in doesn’t matter.

The keyword abstract is used if if it’s meant to be used as a base class to something else I.e have shoe as an abstract class, and trainer (type of shoe) as a class that inherits from shoe. This doesn’t not affect the methods inside

Hope this makes sense